# how to build dynamic database (autonomously operating) in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

My problem is that I want to build a Django Website that has a periodically-automatically-updated databases at the back-end of my django application.
For example, I want to add new record to my database every 5 second, and I wrote my code in models.py as follow:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
import time

class Descriptors(models.Model):
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def add_new_record():
    Descriptor = Descriptors(updated = datetime.datetime.now()).save()
    time.sleep(5)
while True:
    add_new_record()
```

This code does create the record in background when I run `python manage.py startserver`. However, this code will stick at creating the record without starting the server. So is there any idea how I can solve the problem, or which tutorial that I should refer for making a dynamic database at back-end of Django? Thank you.

Comment: So do you wan't to keep on creating a DB entry without starting the server? I don't know why you'd want to do that, but why don't you run a cronjob for 5 min interval to run your python script?

Comment: Yes, I do want to start my server, at the same time, I want the code in the lower part to run in background. Because, in my real code, I actually fetch stock price from a website periodically (says every 5 seconds). And, that fetched stock price will be imported to my database, then being rendered and shown again on my django site.

Comment: Then a cronjob will be your best friend. Although my knowledge is limited but crons are designed for these purposes only.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will try to google Cronjob

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate management command for that:

```
# yourapp/management/commands/create_descriptor.py

import datetime
from django.core.management import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Descriptors.objects.create(updated = datetime.datetime.now())
```

And the line to your crontab (if you're on Unix-compatible system):

```
* * * * * /path/to/your/manage.py create_descriptor
```

Note, however, that the vanilla cron can't invoke a command quicker than every minute, so if you need higher time resolution you may need something like [Celery's beat](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).